# what happends when test classes fail at deployment time?

Tags: unit-test, deployment, failing-tests

Suppose I have some `Apex Classes` and 50 test classes. Out of fifty test classes
one test class fails. What happens at deployment time?

Comment: This question does not show *any* research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire deployment is rolled back. If any tests fail, nothing gets deployed.

From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dev_lifecycle.meta/dev_lifecycle/deploy.htm):

> Deployment is an all-or-nothing event—for example, a single new field on the production organization can make the entire deployment fail if this field does not exist in the deploying organization.

Whereas this is an example of missing metadata, the same applies with unit tests also.

> Deployments that have finished but failed, and deployments that were canceled are listed in the Failed section. No changes were committed to the Salesforce org for these deployments because files were missing, components had errors, tests failed, or the deployment was canceled.

However, there is such a thing as partial deployments to non production orgs, see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dev_lifecycle.meta/dev_lifecycle/migrate_monitor.htm):

> Deployments that have completed successfully or have partially succeeded are listed in the Succeeded section. **Only deployments to a non-production org can partially succeed.** These are deployments that have the rollbackOnError field set to false in the deployment options and have errors in a subset of components. In a partially succeeded deployment, the failed components aren’t committed and the remaining components are committed to the org.